# Use animated background

Tags: ios, animated-gif

So can I use a .Gif as the background in my iPhone application. I have my GFX editor here asking me whether or not I can use .gif. For example if it were the "matrix" effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean for the launch image or for some image you show in the background as the app runs?

Comment: Both, so for example. I will have my splash screen. After that the main view will load with the animated background (.gif).

Comment: The launch image must be a plain old PNG. See the following search for info on showing animated gifs in an iOS app: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+animated+gif

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how you can achieve this. Add an `UIImageView` to background, and set the class of that `UIImageView` to [UIImageView-PlayGIF](https://github.com/yfme/UIImageView-PlayGIF)

UIImageView-PlayGIF is a GitHub Open Source project that lets you play `.gif` images